# Rust Diesel update on joined table

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am trying to update a field in a table use Diesel. I need to verify an association in another table, so I am `LEFT JOIN`-ing the other table. Here is a SQL representation of what I am doing:

```sql
UPDATE table_name AS tn
SET field = 'value'
FROM table_name
LEFT JOIN other_table AS ot
    ON ot.id_field_one = {some_id}
WHERE tn.id_field_one = {some_id} and ot.id_field_two = {some_different_id};
```

Here is what I have tried with Diesel:

```rust
dsl::update(
    table_name
        .left_join(other_table.on(other_table_fields::id_field_one.eq(some_id)))
        .filter(table_fields::id_field_one.eq(some_id))
        .filter(other_table_fields::id_field_two.eq(some_different_id))
)
.set(table_fields::field.eq("value"))
.execute(db_connection)?;
```

I get the following error (I've replaced the table and field names to match the names of my examples above):

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `diesel::query_builder::SelectStatement<JoinOn<diesel::query_source::joins::Join<table_name::table, other_table::table, LeftOuter>, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<other_table::columns::some_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, uuid::Uuid>>>, query_builder::select_clause::DefaultSelectClause, query_builder::distinct_clause::NoDistinctClause, query_builder::where_clause::WhereClause<And<diesel::expression::operators::Eq<other_table::columns::some_different_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, uuid::Uuid>>, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<table_name::columns::id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, uuid::Uuid>>>>>: diesel::query_builder::IntoUpdateTarget` is not satisfied
   --> src/file.rs:297:9
    |
296 |       match dsl::update(
    |             ----------- required by a bound introduced by this call
297 | /         table_name
298 | |             .left_join(other_table.on(other_table_fields::some_id.eq(some_id)))
299 | |             .filter(other_table_fields::some_different_id.eq(some_different_id))
300 | |             .filter(table_fields::id.eq(some_id)),
    | |________________________________________________________________^ the trait `diesel::query_builder::IntoUpdateTarget` is not implemented for `diesel::query_builder::SelectStatement<JoinOn<diesel::query_source::joins::Join<table_name::table, other_table::table, LeftOuter>, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<other_table::columns::some_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, uuid::Uuid>>>, query_builder::select_clause::DefaultSelectClause, query_builder::distinct_clause::NoDistinctClause, query_builder::where_clause::WhereClause<And<diesel::expression::operators::Eq<other_table::columns::some_different_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, uuid::Uuid>>, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<table_name::columns::id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, uuid::Uuid>>>>>`
    |
    = help: the trait `diesel::query_builder::IntoUpdateTarget` is implemented for `diesel::query_builder::SelectStatement<F, query_builder::select_clause::DefaultSelectClause, query_builder::distinct_clause::NoDistinctClause, W>`
note: required by a bound in `diesel::update`
   --> /Users/tanner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel-1.4.8/src/query_builder/functions.rs:80:18
    |
80  | pub fn update<T: IntoUpdateTarget>(source: T) -> UpdateStatement<T::Table, T::WhereClause> {
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `diesel::update`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `JoinOn<diesel::query_source::joins::Join<table_name::table, other_table::table, LeftOuter>, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<other_table::columns::some_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, uuid::Uuid>>>: HasTable` is not satisfied
```

The SQL works when I run it as a query, but I can't figure out how to represent the same thing in working Rust code. What am I missing here?

Comment: Obviously, I could use `diesel::sql_query` with a raw SQL string to do this, but I don't think I get the same built-in protection against SQL injection when doing that (correct me if that is incorrect).

Comment: `diesel::sql_query` uses internally prepared statements, like any other part of diesel. Just make sure to not build the query string via `format!`. Use explicit binds instead.

Answer (score 2):

Diesel does currently not support joins in that position. You can either use `diesel::sql_query` to write the whole query or provide a custom query dsl extension for your specific query.